# C# Downloading Instagram Profile As HTML

Tags: c#, html, download, instagram, html-agility-pack

I have been trying to download an public Instagram profile to the fetch stats such as followers and bio. I have been doing this in a c# console application and downloading the HTML using HTML Agility Pack.

Code:

```
string url = @"https://www.instagram.com/" + Console.ReadLine() + @"/?hl=en";
Console.WriteLine();

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);
document.Save(path1);
```

When I save it though all I get is a bunch of scripts and a blank screen:

[image]

I was wondering how to save the html once all the scripts had run and formed the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ANSWER

Thanks for the suggestions on how to download the HTML! I managed to return some instagram information in the end. Here is the code:

```
//(This was done using HTML Agility Pack)

string url = @"https://www.instagram.com/" + Console.ReadLine() + @"/?hl=en";

HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load(url);

var metas = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("meta");
var followers = metas.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.HasProperty("name", "description"));

if (followers == null) { Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Can't Find Profile :("); return; }

var content = followers.Attributes["content"].Value.StopAt('-');

Console.WriteLine(content);
```

And HasProperty() & StopAt()

```
public static bool HasProperty(this HtmlNode node, string property, params string[] valueArray)
{
    var propertyValue = node.GetAttributeValue(property, "");
    var propertyValues = propertyValue.Split(' ');
    return valueArray.All(c => propertyValues.Contains(c));
}

public static string StopAt(this string input, char stopAt)
{
    int x = input.IndexOf(stopAt);
    return input.Substring(0, x);
}
```

## NOTE:

However this is still not the answer I am looking for. I still have a wreck of HTML which is not structred the same as the HTML I recieve when I look at it in Google Chrome. Doing some searching in the HTML I managed to scalvage the content-less html for a meta tag which contains the content. This is okay for this but if I going to continue this method of finding HTML content then it may not be the same :(

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve content using a web request, it returns a HTML document which is then rendered by the browser to display the content.

Right now, you're saving the HTML document given to you by the server. Instead of doing this, you need to render it before getting the details. One way to do this is using a web browser control. If you set the URL to the instragram URL, let the rendering engine handle it and once the load event is fired by the control, you can get the rendered HTML output.

From there, you can deserialize as an XmlDocument and identify exactly what details you need to retrieve from the rendered output.

Comment: I have tried using the Windows Forms WebBrowser then saving the Document using Stream Writer. However this only returns the head and body tags nothing else. I am developing on C# Console Application does the webBrowser work on this? Also i had to change the thread "because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment"

Answer (score 0):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WB_1.Navigate(@"https://www.instagram.com/" + Console.ReadLine() + @"/?hl=en");

        WB_1.LoadCompleted += wb_LoadCompleted;
    }

    void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic doc = WB_1.Document;
        string htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: How do you wait until it is loaded though?

Comment: @BenWebb Use the `LoadCompleted` event

Comment: I have got your code to work but it has no difference to my original output using the HTML agility pack